# NetSuite - Merge Support Case via SuiteScript 2x UE

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to merge support cases which come in from emails if the title is the same.

I am using the N/task module to get this, but is there another way to merge Cases?

This returns null as SUPPORT_CASE is not a supported enum.

```
task.DedupeEntityType.SUPPORT_CASE;
```

This is my entire block of task submission.

```
const mergeTask = task.create({taskType: task.TaskType.ENTITY_DEDUPLICATION});
mergeTask.entityType = task.DedupeEntityType.SUPPORT_CASE;
mergeTask.masterSelectionMode = task.MasterSelectionMode.SELECT_BY_ID;
mergeTask.masterRecordId = duplicateId;
mergeTask.dedupeMode = task.DedupeMode.MERGE;
mergeTask.recordIds = [newRecord.id];
mergeTask.startOn = new Date();
mergeTask.submit();
```

Error:

`task.submit: Missing a required argument: EntityDeduplicationTask.entityType`

Answer (score 1):

As you rightly mention, SUPPORT_CASE is not a valid Enum. For other people reading this answer, only the following values are permitted:

- CUSTOMER
- CONTACT
- VENDOR
- PARTNER
- LEAD
- PROSPECT

Further reading: https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43731/loc/en_US

In regards to a solution to your question, I would implement the following in a USER EVENT script (before submit):

- Capture the SUBJECT value from the incoming email
- Use saved search (N/search) to compare this value to the TITLE of the case in question
- If an EXACT MATCH is found:

  - create a new MESSAGE record (N/record)
  - Add contents of email to the body of message record
  - Link it to the case in question
  - save

Note - the above presumes that all case titles are UNIQUE. If they are not, you may need a secondary script (like M/R or scheduled script) which can merge duplicates on a nightly basis.